# Generic Function to Output to UITextField or UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

I am trying to write a function in Swift 2 for iOS that processes some text and writes it to either a `UITextField` *or* a `UILabel`. Currently, I have the following that works:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabal: UILabel!

​func writeSomeText(string: String, toOutput: UITextField) {
   // do some text processing
   toOutput.text = // processed string
}

​func writeSomeText(string: String, toOutput: UILabel) {
   // do some text processing
   toOutput.text = // processed string
}
```

As you see, right now I am overloading the function, essentially duplicating it for both UITextField and UILabel, and since I have a bunch of text processing that is exactly the same, I am duplicating code.

Is there any way to write a function using generics to achieve this with one function definition?

Comment: of course there is, write a protocol that has a text property which is settable and make your second argument an object that conforms to this protocol

Answer (score 2):

try look at this approach ...

```
import UIKit

protocol P {
    func foo(str: String)->String
}
extension P {
    func foo(str: String)->String {
        // do some processing
        let res = str
        return res
    }
}
extension UILabel:P {
    func bar(str: String) {
        self.text = foo(str)
    }
}
extension UITextField:P {
    func bar(str: String) {
        self.text = foo(str)
    }
}

let l = UILabel()
l.text = "alfa"
l.bar("ALFA")

let t = UITextField()
t.text = "beta"
t.bar("BETA")

print(l.text, t.text) // Optional("ALFA") Optional("BETA")
```

by the way, you don't need protocol P at all  :-), it is there just as a 'namespace' (not to have a global func foo)

another approach is to define some common protocol and extend UILabel and UITextField

```
import UIKit

protocol P: class {
    var text: String? {get set}
}

extension UILabel: P {}
extension UITextField: P {}

func writeSomeText<T:P>(string: String, toOutput: T ){
    // do some text processing
    toOutput.text = string
}

let l = UILabel()
writeSomeText("label", toOutput: l)
l.text // "label"

let tv = UITextView()
tv.text = "text"
// but
writeSomeText("text view", toOutput: tv) // error: cannot invoke 'writeSomeText' with an argument list of type '(String, toOutput: UITextView)'
```

later you can extend other classes with text property, if you want ... without changing implementation of func writeSomeText

Comment: This is a great solution and works perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :-), if you are happy with my answer, you are welcome to accept it, too

Answer (score 1):

A **Swifty** way (without Generics) would be

```
@objc
protocol UITextOutputProtocol: class {
    func setOutputText(text: String)
}

extension UITextField : UITextOutputProtocol {
    func setOutputText(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

extension UILabel : UITextOutputProtocol {
    func setOutputText(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //An outlet Collection containing Labels and TextField
    @IBOutlet var texts: [UITextOutputProtocol]!

    //An example function that will be replicating a text in all controls
    func setTexts() {
        for text in texts {
            text.setOutputText("example Text")
        }
    }
```

> **UPDATE:**

As `UILabel` and `UITextField` are now implementing protocol `UITextOutputProtocol` the following code will work.

```
   @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

   ​func writeSomeText(string: String, toOutput: UITextOutputProtocol) {
     // do some text processing
     toOutput.setOutputText("example Text") // change the text here for your processed string
   }

   func doSomeProcessingOnText(text:String) {
     writeSomeText(text, textField)
     writeSomeText(text, textLabel)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hugo, and what about  " ... since I have a **bunch of text processing** that is exactly the same, I am duplicating code ... " ? and how works @IBOutlet var texts: [UITextOutputProtocol]! How to create it in storyboard ???

Comment: This is just an example, for this case in Storyboard, I just linked a Label and a TextField to an OutletCollection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a hack since `UITextField` and `UILabel` don't conform any shared protocols for text editing, but you could use KVO:

```
func writeSomeText(string: String, output: AnyObject) {
    // do some text processing
    if output.respondsToSelector("text") {
        output.setValue(string, forKey: "text")
    }
}
```

`respondsToSelector` checks to make sure the object you're passing in has a property `text` before continuing setting a value to that key.  This check is used to prevent a crash a runtime if you pass in an object that is not KVO compliant for the key text`.

Comment: so UITextView is another 'candidate', isn't it? I am not an expert for Cocoa or CocoaTouch, but probably there is a longer list of objects with text property

Comment: Maybe, but this question isn't about `UITextView` (at least according to the OP).  Theoretically, this answer would work with any object containing a `text` property which is a String.  This would crash if `output` was an object that has a `text` property which was not a String.